# Could not use HiveDrivers on a Wildfly 10 server and JaxRs

Tags: java, hive, jax-rs, wildfly, cloudera

I'm trying to implement a Hive Connection in a Wildfly 10 App with jaxrs service.

The app works like a charm, but, the moment when I add in the maven dependencies the hive driver:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
                <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3</version>
            </dependency>
```

The entire app brokes and stops to work. The wildfly server still serves the static content (like the jsp pages and the images) but everything that needs to be computed in the jaxrs Application class simply return a 500 and this error message:

```
17:01:41,053 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-2) UT005023: Exception handling request to /webapp1/app/file: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003190: Could not find constructor for class: org.apache.slider.server.appmaster.web.rest.AMWebServices
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceBuilder.constructor(ResourceBuilder.java:692)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.resourcefactory.POJOResourceFactory.registered(POJOResourceFactory.java:42)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:208)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:194)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:180)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addResourceFactory(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:157)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.addPerRequestResource(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:76)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.registration(ResteasyDeployment.java:404)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:245)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:113)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:231)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.getServlet(ManagedServlet.java:170)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

These are my maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-multipart-provider -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
             <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
          <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
          <version>4.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
         </dependency>

         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>


         <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180130</version>
        </dependency>

   </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a JAR file conflict. The Hive JDBC driver has a transitive dependency on the Apache Slider library at an earlier/later version than the one required by your application at runtime.

You can exclude this dependency as follows which will prevent it being deployed with your application:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.slider</groupId>
            <artifactId>slider-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

You have also tagged your question with Cloudera and in my recent experience you need to use the Cloudera version of the JDBC driver corresponding to your Cloudera server.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc?repo=cloudera

As slider doesn't appear to be a transitive dependency of the Hive JDBC driver at versions < 2, you would not then need to bother with this exclusion.